# Mark an email as read when already opened through another folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have several folders which may contain identical emails.
Example: my Inbox contains everything except some emails that I officially excluded through rules/filters.
Then I have a "only to me" folder so I can quickly go thro

Comment: Agree with what John mentioned above, you need to open the email in each folder. As I know, with options in Outlook client alone, we could not mark duplicate emails in different folders as read when only opened through one folder automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a copy of an email (by Rule or whatever) in a different folder, it becomes a different email (to Outlook). So opening email A in Folder T does not open the same email (now B) in Folder X. Each email is a different record in the Outlook database (local or server).

So you need to open the email in each folder.

The "Marked as" Rule variations in Outlook Rules do not mark as "Read"

I try to manage this myself by Folderizing (as you do) but minimizing and not having duplicates.